# Laravel 4 $view->nest() with workbench view

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Pretty new to  Laravel 4, I like it a lot. I'm working on making my application extendable with my workbench. I want to nest views so I can extend things like site navigation and other features in the core view files.

Before making my workbench I tested with a view::composer and a test template, worked perfect. I then switched over to my workbench and in its Controller file (for testing atm) I do the following:

```
public function getIndex()
{
     View::composer('*navigation', function($view)    
        {    

          $view->nest('test','default/admin/test');    
        //$view->nest('test','l4cp-support::navigation');    
    });

    return View::make('l4cp-support::navigation');
}
```

The uncommented nest works perfect, without error, the commented out one crashes my server (iis) and leaves no error.

The return View::make works perfectly fine!

My next step is to try a composer.php file, I've seen it mentioned here and there but if anyone has some idea as to why this is occurring I'd love to read it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We'll I have not gotten much help here. I tested nesting with other templates and found for some reason I cannot nest on my navigation, at least with a vendor package rendered template, nesting on my site layout was ok.